# Search and remove auto-generated comment paragraph from all java classes

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I have a eclipse web project and the scale of project is very big. Every class has auto generated paragraph talking about the license and stuff, but I want to remove this paragraph from all the classes.
Is there any fast way of searching and removing it in eclipse? 
For some of the reason I can't put the whole paragraph in eclipse native search option.

Comment: You could open the project folder in sublime text and use a regex to replace the occurrences of the comment with nothing.

Comment: @xsquared No need for Sublime, Eclipse itself has this functionality.

Comment: Or do the same in eclipse. Search - File ... enter your search regex, check the regex checkbox, select your scope, hit the replace button

Comment: Having hundred of classes is not a reason for java-EE

Comment: Good to know. Back in the days Eclipse wasn't capable of that. How time flies ...

Comment: Hm, in most licenses I know one is not allowed to remove those license paragraphs - just a comment...

Comment: @BackSlash for some of the reason i can not search the whole paragraph using the Eclipse native search.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to solve your issue by adjusting code style by `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates` and applying new code formatter excluding autogenerated comments. Also I recommend you to try [JAutoDoc plugin](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/), AFAIK it helps modifying the way classes should look.